find Cosmos RU in custom dimension of Application Insight
I am looking to get RU usage and saw the post How to get RU of a query in Dependencies through Application Insights Analytics Tool? but yet the response header is not coming in the custom dimension.
Code used
dependencies | where type == "Azure DocumentDB" | join ( requests  ) on operation_Id 
I am hoping to get RU count for the query

Making sure that your code logs the RequestCharge as a custom dimension in Application Insights and extracts it from the response is crucial. After that is finished, you may use Application Insights Analytics to query for it.
